# How to join sql tables correctly to avoid data repetition?

Tags: sql

I have these tables: Doctors,DoctorRoles,Patients.

I am trying to create a new table using foreign keys, which will display the details of the doctor from Doctors table(Name: Alan Smith) the role from DoctorRoles(Nurse) and the patients he is in charge of from Patients table.

However when I run the sql query Alan Smith is assigned to every patient however some patients are not seen by this doctor, so how do I make it that a patient is linked to the correct doctor? Currently I'm not sure how to the link the two so example code would be helpful.

Doctors table: DoctorID, Forename,Surname|PatientID,Forename,Surname

DoctorRoles: RoleID,Role|DoctorID,Forename,Surname

Patient:PatientID,Forename,Surname,DOB|DoctorID,Forename,Surname|Role

```
Select DoctorID, Forename,Surname,Role,Patient.Forenmae,Patient.Surname,Patient.DOB
From Doctors,DoctorRoles,Patient
```

Comment: (1) Tag the question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) Show the query you are currently using.

Comment: What the foreign key relationships? I am assuming that the DoctorRoles and Patients tables have a single foreign key relating back to the Doctors table but you need to state that for someone to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Isn't there a table for the assignments of patients to doctors?

Comment: I don’t see any foreign keys in your tables. Your Doctors table should have a foreign key to the DoctorRoles and your Patients table should have a foreign key to the Doctors table.

Comment: Apologies, looking back at my question I should have been clearer. I have added what is in my tables, I am using sql within visual studio.

Comment: I have added the querey that I've tried at the moment each doctor is being assigned to everey patient. i'm not sure how to link a doctor to a unique group of patiens for example mothers to midwives.

Comment: Redesign the tables. Add columns in Patients and DoctorRoles that reference the Doctors table. Otherwise there is no solution to your problem.

Comment: I've shown my updated tables, would that be a correct way to do it?

Comment: As to redesigning the tables: If you have a patientid in the doctors table, it means a doctor has one patient only. This would be weird. If you have a doctorid in the patients table, it means a patient has one doctor only (at least per patientid). Ask yourself: How many roles can a doctor have? Does the role have a relation to the patient? You may want to ask a new question tagged with "database-design".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join the Doctors table to the other 2 with inner joins:

```
Select d.DoctorID, d.Forename, d.Surname, r.Role, p.Forename, p.Surname, p.DOB
From Doctors d 
inner join DoctorRoles r on r.DoctorID = d.DoctorID
inner join Patient p on p.DoctorID = d.DoctorID
```

For this to work, there must be a role assigned for each doctor and at least a patient. 
If not, use left joins:

```
Select d.DoctorID, d.Forename, d.Surname, r.Role, p.Forename, p.Surname, p.DOB
From Doctors d 
left join DoctorRoles r on r.DoctorID = d.DoctorID
left join Patient p on p.DoctorID = d.DoctorID
```

Comment: You probably to reverse the relationship between Doctors and DoctorRoles. That way if there are only X number of DoctorRoles, the DoctorRoles table will only have X rows.

Comment: The design is so poor. There is no way this to stand. But this is the OP's decision: doctors and their roles and their patients.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's starting to make more sense, I will mark it as the answer. To clear up i have a couple of questions. One is when I make this query it will just pull the neccessary dat but I'm assuming to actually create the table I just add the create table above the code you have provided? Also In my doctors table I would have to add the patient columns how would that be done? And finally I'm assuming I would have to maually assign patients to a doctor in the doctors table by writing out the data myself?

Comment: If the tables don't exist you must execute the `create table...` statements first. You don't need to add patient columns in the doctor's table. If in patients table there is a column doctorid then this doctor is assigned to that patient. So for each patient there must be a doctor.

Comment: What is poor about the design? I'm genuinely asking because normally in assignments I get the tables given to me so I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You could also use the SELECT INTO to create the table on the fly.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You know that you changed at least 3 times the schema since you first asked the question. So I guess  this is an ongoing process. Now: you have a main table Doctors. Each doctor can have 1 or multiple roles? That's for you to decide and design the roles table in such a way that can or cannot accept the same doctor assigned to multiple roles. Each doctor can have multiple patients, right? But doctors can change patients. If this is a school assignment I guess maybe you won't go that deep and keep things simple.

Comment: @forpas Are you using self join on Patient table? Why cannot I use inner join Patient p on p.DoctorID = d.DoctorID

Answer (score 0):

```
Doctors table: DoctorID, Forename,Surname, RoleID

DoctorRoles table: RoleID,Role

Patients table:PatientID,Forename,Surname, DOB, DoctorID
```

Making my best guess at your data, I think this should be your table definitions.